# Two consecutive click events not triggering the change event on Safari browsers

Tags: javascript, html, safari, dom-events

Exactly what the title says.

Example html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <input type='file' style="display: none" id='button' />
    <script>
        const b = document.getElementById('button');
        b.addEventListener('change', () => {
            console.log('changed');
        });
        function foo() {
            b.click();
            b.click();
        }
    </script>
    <span onclick="foo()">Click</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Here if I click on the span,
**On browsers NOT Safari**
The file picker open twice, and the change event occurs as expected.
**On Safari**
The file picker shows up JUST ONCE, and even if I select a file, the change event does NOT trigger.

I could not find a valid documentation for this unfortunately. Anybody has any ideas?

Comment: Try `input` event

Comment: By "browsers NOT Safari" to be understood "Chrome"? Because in Firefox the picker opens once, and the event fires as expected, while in Chrome, even if it opens twice, event fires only once, when the last picker is closed.